# Using javascript function to launch mignific popup

Tags: jquery, function, magnific-popup, input-field

Good Morning,

I've been scrounging the internet for a solution to the following and have turned up with nothing. The effect I want is for magnific popup to show an image after entering data into an input field. I theorize I can accomplish this if I can launch the jquery using a function().

On my webpage I have:

```
<a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  <img id="activity" width="100%" src="bin/pear.png" />
</div>

    <script>
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true
});
    </script>
```

It popup works great from the "Show inline popup" link.

I would like it to popup after hitting the enter key after inputting data into a field...

```
    var page = new Array("apple","banana","pear");
    function redirect(){
        if(page.indexOf(document.forms["login"]["pass"].value)!=-1){
            document.getElementById('activity').src= "bin/" + document.forms["login"]["pass"].value + ".png";
            document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
            document.activeElement.blur();
        }
        else {
            window.location = "index.html";
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So in essence if I enter in "pear" a picture of a pear pops up. If I enter in "banana" a picture of a banana pops up.

I have it working perfectly from the text link, but cannot figure out how to get it to launch after pressing enter from the input field.

I assume it is a simple rookie move on my part not knowing what line of code to add to my redirect function.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to enable the user to press the enter key in your input field, then you need to add an on key listener and apply your logic for the keyCode 13. [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp)

Comment: Probably not the cleanest method but your comment helped me discover the usefulness of "document.getElementById("myBtn").click()" so thank you. I don't see how to give your answer positive feedback.

Comment: You can upvote the comment, but did you find a solution that works?